# Implementation of methods of interface

Tags: c++, inheritance, matrix, iterator, polymorphism

I want to implement a representation of matrices. for that I have two types of matrices - regular and sparse, which differ in their implementation - one holds a vector, and the second a map of indices and value, both inherit from `Matrix` class.
For that, I'm using the strategy pattern, where I create the base abstract class `Matrix`, two classes that inherit from `Matrix` - `RegMatrix` and `SparseMatrix`, and `MyMatrix` that holds a pointer to a `Matrix`.

I want to implement the `+` operator, which operates on `Matrix` and receives another `Matrix`. but when I implement the `+` operator, I might receive as parameter sparse/regular matrix.

so I have 2 questions:

1. The only hint I have is to create an iterator of type "matrix", and implement the iterator for each type of matrix (regular and sparse). 
   how can I do such a thing?
2. Let's say I implemented an iterator for both types of "matrix". how can I use the different iterators, in case I have to add two different types of matrices? do I have to implement all 4 different cases?

The operator+ looks like:

```
Matrix& operator+(const Matrix& other)
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this with an iterator, but with a hard-coded type check and separate code for all three cases. If you're serious about numerical programming, don't go all object-oriented, at least not in your inner loops. (Template code could be fast enough, though.)

Comment: When and how do you choose which implementation is used? This is the core question of the entire problem and will dictate whether OOP is even useful in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer not to implement the functionality in the base class.

Implement the functionality in each of the child classes. This will allow for use of optimal algorithms.

Or you could declare getters and setters as abstract in the Base class and use them in your base class implementation:

```
struct Matrix_Base
{
  virtual int   get_value(unsigned int row, unsigned int column) = 0;
  virtual void  set_value(int value, unsigned int row, unsigned int column) = 0;
  Matrix_Base operator+(const Matrix_Base& other)
  {
    // perform addition
    int sum = get_value(row, column) + other.get_value(column, row);
    set_value(sum, row, column);
    //...
  }
};
```

Remember, when passing a Matrix, the receiving function can only use common functions (interface) of the Matrix.  For specifics, functions will have to use specialized (descendants) in the parameter lists.

Comment: If you use `operator+()` you should return new instance to a matrix. Use `operator+=()` instead if you modify the existing instance. Other than that I would use this approach if performance isn't a requirement and implement all the matrix operations in terms of `set/get_value()` functions, preferably as free functions, not members.

Comment: @JarkkoL:  Good point, but I was focusing on getters and setters rather than the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement + operator only for RegMatrix and 2 conversion operators:
1. From RegMatrix to SparseMatrix
2. From SparseMatrix to RegMatrix

What are performance requirements?

Comment: there are no specific performance requirements,
but the switching between matrices is ONLY when the number of zeros is less than half (regular), or more than half (sparse)